vscode Minimize-Maximize toggle button not working
My vsocde's fullscreen toggle button is not working on windows 11.
You can see what button I am mentioning
I have searched my question online and found that
Window Controls Overlay: Enabled
is causing the problem but right now this setting is missing on my vscode.
And I know I can use F11 but that's not what I need!
Worth mentioning that I have this issue since I installed some extentions such as:
Apc Customize UI++, VSCode Animations, Vibrancy Continued.
But after uninstalling them still have the issue and it doesn't help.
Please help me with this. Thanks!
I have tried uninstalling the extentions but it didn't work!
I have tried Win+Up arrow keys but it didn't work!
My only option right now is F11 which is useless.
